# Save image as stream and then display

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I eventually want to save my images in a database, but for now a file will do.

I have started with

```
    with open("blue.png", "rb") as imageFile:
        f = imageFile.read()
        b = bytearray(f)
    with open("blue.bytes", "w") as streamFile:
        f = streamFile.write(str(b))
```

This gives me a file that looks like:

```
bytearray(b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x0 ...
```

Is this right so far?

How can I then read it back and convert to an image?
I confess to being hopelessly confused about whether I want bytes or a bytearray and how to get this string back into that form

I include here my attempt at working it through, but I'm aware it doesn't work

```
import wx
from io import BytesIO


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Demonstrate wxPython image')
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.save_stream()

    def save_stream(self):
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap('blue.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        with open("blue.png", "rb") as imageFile:
            f = imageFile.read()
            b = str(bytearray(f))
        with open("blue.bytes", "w") as streamFile:
            f = streamFile.write(b)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        """Initialise the class."""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        file_image_sizer = self._image_from_file()
        stream_image_sizer = self._image_from_stream()
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_sizer.Add(file_image_sizer, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(stream_image_sizer, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

    def _image_from_file(self):
        image_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap('red.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
        static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
        image_sizer.Add(static_bitmap)
        return image_sizer

    def _image_from_stream(self):
        image_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
        with open("blue.bytes", "rb") as imageFile:
            f = imageFile.read()
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(BytesIO(bytes(f)), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
        static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
        image_sizer.Add(static_bitmap)
        return image_sizer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    main_frame.Show(True)
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Following Robin's answer I have changed the _image_from_stream function to read:

```
def _image_from_stream(self):
    image_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
    with open("blue.bytes", "r") as imageFile:
        image = wx.Image(imageFile)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image)
    static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
    static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
    image_sizer.Add(static_bitmap)
    return image_sizer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's data and not text then you'll want to keep it as bytes or bytearray, not str.

In wxPython4 you can load an image from a file or file-like object, and convert to a bitmap (if needed) like this:

```
image = wx.Image(file_object)
bmp = wx.Bitmap(image)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made the changes you suggested (see updated question). I get the message "Stream warning: Unknown data format". My wx version is 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix)

Comment: Is blue.bytes still a valid PNG file? (And is there a reason you are creating that file other than just for illustration for this question.) You may need to open it with mode "rb" to ensure it isn't being interpreted as text.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused between text and binary data. That's cleared it up